# Java How can i have multiple rectangles at once

Tags: java, swing

I want to draw a rectangle at the mouse x and y. I want there to be lots of rectangles so if i was to click at the 50 ,50 coordinate on the JFrame it would draw a rectangle and then if i clicked somewhere else it would draw another rectangle there, but not delete the other one so i could have clicked 5 times (<--example) then i would have five rectangles all at once.

The rectangles are supposed to have a fixed height and width as well, so when you click on a specific area it will draw a 10 x 10 rectangle and it will remember all the other rectangles already drawn and keep them drawn in the same place and also how do i paint it the arraylist(if there is one)

my code:

public class Game extends Canvas  implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
public boolean running = false;
public static final String title = "tilebased game!";

private Thread thread;
public int height = 600;
public int width = 800;
private Dimension d = new Dimension(width, height);
public static Rectangle block;
public static Rectangle[] blocks = new Rectangle[2];
public static int blocknum = 0;
public static int xCreate;
public static int yCreate;
public static int xcoord;
public static int ycoord;
 public static ArrayList<Rectangle> rects = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();


public static boolean islicked = false;

public Game() {
    setPreferredSize(d);
    setMinimumSize(d);
    setMaximumSize(d);
    addMouseListener(new tile());
    addMouseMotionListener(new tile());

}



public void start() {


    running = true;
    new Thread(this).start();

}

public void stop() {

    running = false;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game g = new Game();
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(g);
    f.pack();
    f.setTitle(title);
    f.setResizable(false);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
    g.start();

}

public void run() {
    while(running){
        tick();
        render();
    }

    try{
        Thread.sleep(5);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}


public void render() {
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null) {
        createBufferStrategy(2);
        return;
    }
    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.white);


    for (int i = 0; i < rects.size(); i++) {
        Rectangle rect = rects.get(i);

    }


    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}

public  void tick() {

}
```

}

and the other class.

```
    public class tile implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {


    public static Game game;
public Image img;

public static boolean clicked = false;
public tile tile;



@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Game.xcoord = e.getX();
    Game.ycoord = e.getY();
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    Game.rects.add(new Rectangle(Game.xcoord,Game.ycoord,10,10));
    System.out.println("hi mayte");


}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton()== MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        clicked = true;


    Game.xcoord = e.getX();
    Game.ycoord = e.getY();
    clicked = true;
    }

}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if(e.getButton()== MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
        clicked = true;
        System.out.println("hi mayte");


    Game.xcoord = e.getX();
    Game.ycoord = e.getY();
    clicked = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How does this question differ from [java : multiple rectangles at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386128/java-multiple-rectangles-at-once)

Comment: I would recommend adding the elements into a LinkedList, iterate over it in the rendering method and paint them all. You may also have to define certain things, such as: a rectangle will only be added if the displacement of the mouse press and mouse release is greater than 0. That is presuming you want dynamic rectangle sizes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can make an ArrayList of Rectangles:

```
ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
```

and then add rectangles to it (fill and put this in mouseClicked):

```
rectangles.add(new Rectangle(..));
```

after that, you can iterate through this array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rectangles.size(); i++) {
    Rectangle rect = rectangles.get(i);
    // paint methods here
}
```

and remove any rectangle from collection:

```
rectangles.remove(5); // removes fifth element
```

ArrayList is a class responsible for storing dynamic amount of objects. It's size changes during work.

Comment: @user2279603, why are you wasting peoples time? You where given the answer to this question yesterday. Asking duplicate questions and ignoring advice will cause people to ignore your question in the future.

Comment: @Adrian, trashgod already noted in the comment above that this was a duplicate question. By answering you are encouraging this behaviour.

Comment: @camickr, I see, i did see this question 1-2 days before but i wasn't sure why it was asked again? I thought people ignored him.

Comment: @Sage, what do you mean people ignored him? There where 3 answers given.

Comment: @camickr, No i didn't mean that. Don't get me wrong, I just thought that. But your comment here made that clear. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: i didnt understand the other answers cause im not 100% smart and if you have any idea of how to draw the arraylist pls tell me sorry if im annoying you

Comment: @user2279603, you where given working code!!! What more do you expect??? No the code is not 100% exactly what you need, but we are here to point you in the right direction not write your code. Most of the code you have here is wrong. As Sage has mention you should not extend Canvas. In addition you should not be using a BufferStrategy since Swing is already double buffered. You should not be using static variables. I would suggest you start with a working example and customize it to your requirements, that is why I provided you with the link.

Comment: ok thanks but calm down and i used your link bye the way

Comment: it was 99.9% what i needed but it was dragging it to the size and i was hoping or a fixed size

Comment: So customize the code. Again we are not here to write the code for you. In fact making it a fixed size is much easier so the code should be easy to change.

Comment: but i dont now how thats why im asking the question im not forcing you to answer i just would like to now

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how? The code you posted here looks nothing like the code suggested in the other posting. You are not using an ArrayList anywhere. So you have given no indication that you have bothered to read the examples from the other posting. So how do you expect us to help when the code you have posted shows no effort that you have listened to past suggestions. There is no way we can help you based on your posted code because it would require a complete rewrite.

Comment: Again, start with something that works. You don't need the code for the colored rectangles so get rid of it. You don't need the code for dragging to draw the rectangle so get rid of it. All you need is code to add a Rectangle to the ArrayList on a mousePressed. So take a look how the current code adds the Rectangle and then move that code to the mousePressed event instead of the mouseReleased event. Then if you have problems you have a program that you can post that shows you have made an effort.

Comment: ok ill  update my question code and then you can help

Comment: its updtaed now how do i paint it

Comment: Did you even read anything I suggested? I basically told you that your current code is completely wrong. In addition to  comments I have already made there is no need for a rendering loop. What part of "start with something that works" do you not understand?

Comment: i am trying.......................................

Comment: just to let you now your code helped me and i fixed it im happy :P

Comment: @user2279603, so then why haven't you accepted the answer that helped. I sure hope you didn't fix "your code" but instead used the code suggestions from the other posting.

Comment: i used most of the code from your suggestion

Comment: when i get to 43 rectangles the game crashes and there is an error that says: Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
 at test.game.Game.render(Game.java:117)
 at test.game.Game.run(Game.java:94)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)                                                 and i need help can you help me.

Comment: @user2279603 Go and search for synchronizaton in Internet.